# javascript repeatable function on click

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I have this code where the user clicks on a div id of `Open_Waters` and the code adds the geojson to the map, changed the text to Remove Open Waters
and then when the user clicks on the Remove Open Waters the layer gets removed.

```
    $("#Open_Waters").click(function(){
        if ($("#Open_Waters").html()=='Open Waters'){
            open_waters.addTo(map);
            $("#Open_Waters").html("Remove Open Waters");
      } else{
            map.removeLayer(open_waters);
            $("#Open_Waters").html("Open Waters");
        }
    });
```

works totally fine

My question: how I can create a function of this with 3 parameters

```
1.div id  2.div text 3.geojson layer
```

I am trying to formulate this function like

```
function legend_click(id, id_displayed, layer){
    $("#${id}").click()
        }
```

I am getting confused on the click method function...

```
id = "#Open_Waters"
id_displayes="Open Waters"
layer=open_waters
```

Comment: Try $(this).click()

Comment: what are `id, id_displayed, layer` in your sample code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this to work

```
function legend_click(id, id_displayed, layer) {
    $(id).click(function () {
        if ($(id).html() == id_displayed) {
            layer.addTo(map);
            $(id).html("Remove " + id_displayed);
        } else {
            map.removeLayer(layer);
            $(id).html(id_displayed);
        }
    })
};
```

Answer (score 0):

`.click` is your event listener, so you want to call your function inside of it.

```
$("#Open_Waters").click(function(){
    your_new_function(id, id_displayed, layer) ...
});

function your_new_function(id, id_displayed, layer){...
```

Comment: no sorry I meant I want to create this generic function outside the click event so I can reuse it multiple times on different layers

Comment: I understand I need the click event to trigger the function but I don't want to keep creating this function...

Comment: That's exactly what I meant, the function declaration is outside of the `.click` function

Comment: okay I see, is it possible to have the .click event inside the function?

Comment: You can define an eventhandler (like `click`) inside the function, but that would just initialize the event handler, it won't run it. What is the purpose of doing that, what do you want to achieve?

Comment: I got this to work `function legend_click(id, id_displayed, layer) {
            $(id).click(function () {
                if ($(id).html() == id_displayed) {
                    layer.addTo(map);
                    $(id).html("Remove " + id_displayed);
                } else {
                    map.removeLayer(layer);
                    $(id).html(id_displayed);
                }
            })
        };`